# Can an abstract base class pointer call the functions of a derived class that are not overridden?

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to use an abstract base class pointer to call a derived class function that is not overridden, but I am unable to call it. We are able to call an overridden function by a base class pointer pointing to a derived class object, so why can’t we call other member functions of the derived class by the base class pointer?

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelated language tags. C is completely different from C++, and doesn't have classes or base pointers. Please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it (like showing us a [mcve] of what you're doing).

Comment: Show a [example].

Comment: Because that's what overridden means. It means you can call a derived class function though a base class pointer.

Comment: If you have an example, try it. If not, make one.

Answer (score 3):

When a method is called on an object, the compiler generates machine code to call the method in one of two different ways:

- if the method is not `virtual`, the method of the same class that the pointer is typed as gets called directly. This jump is calculated statically at compile-time. Any possibility of a derived class is not taken into account.
- if the method is `virtual`, the most derived overridden version of the method gets called. This jump is resolved via dynamic dispatch at run-time, typically (but not required) by using virtual method tables (vtables) containing pointers to the most-overridden methods in each class of the object’s class hierarchy.

Only `virtual` methods particulate in dynamic dispatch.  A derived class method is callable via a base class pointer only if the method is `virtual` in the base class and overridden in the derived class.

Otherwise, the base class method is called directly instead. In which case, the only way to call a derived class method is to downcast the base class pointer to the correct derived class type and them call the method via the resulting pointer.

For example:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { }
    void nonVirtualMethod() { }
    virtual void virtualMethod() { }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void nonVirtualMethod() { }
    void virtualMethod() override { }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base *b = &d;
    b->nonVirtualMethod(); // calls Base::nonVirtualMethod()
    static_cast<Derived*>(b)->nonVirtualMethod(); // calls Derived::nonVirtualMethod()
    b->virtualMethod(); // calls Derived::virtualMethod()
}
```

Comment: This is my question that why we cannot access a derived  member function that  is not overridden by a base class pointer even though we have assigned it address of  derived class  object address?

Comment: @MussabMehboob You are just restating your original question again. So there is no point in asking it again. What exactly about my answer doesn’t address your question?